# Python win32com - Read text in a text box to a cell?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com

I would like to read the text from a text box in an Excel File and save that value to a variable. The problem I am having is with the reading of the TextBox. I have tried several methods, this one showed the most promise, as it does not generate an error, but it does not elicit the desired result either.  Any suggestions are appreciated. See code below.

```
import win32com.client as win32 
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\users\\khillstr\\Testing\\Scripts\\Book1.xlsx")
excel.Visible = False

ws = wb.Worksheets

canvas = excel.ActiveSheet.Shapes

for shp in canvas.CanvasItems:
    if shp.TextFrame.Characters:
        print shp.TextFrame.Characters
    else:
        print "no"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text in a textbox object on a sheet you need to use `shp.TextFrame.Characters.Caption` as the `Characters` method returns a `Characters` object and not a string.

Comment: Logically that makes sense, but I get an error when I try it. 
Runtime error <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'function' object has no attribute 'Caption'

Comment: A shot in the dark, but try `shp.TextFrame2.TextRange`

Comment: That worked!! I swear I tried it before, but I must have tweaked something else in the meantime. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Canvas has to do with graphics in excel files.  I think you want access to the cells.  Below is code that prints out each row as a tuple.

```
import win32com.client as win32 
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\users\\khillstr\\Testing\\Scripts\\Book1.xlsx")
excel.Visible = False

sheet = wb.Worksheets(1)

for row in sheet.UsedRange.Value:
  print row
```

Comment: Oddly enough, Excel groups its worksheet textboxes under the shapes object.

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32com.client as win32

file_name = 'path_to_excel'

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(self.file_name)
excel.Visible = False

sheet = wb.Worksheets(1)
deep = lambda r,c: sheet.Cells(r,c)
print(deep(row_num,col_num))

excel.Application.Quit()
```

This code will open an excel located at 'path_to_excel' and read a cell located at (Row_Number = row_num, Column_Number = col_num)

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.